# An unexpected UI error on adaptive cards, accessing from MS Teams android app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a message extension running in MS teams. The UI is based on Adaptive Cards.

While testing I saw a strange UI error on the Microsoft teams android app. Please refer to the images below for both iOS and Android.

This strange **line** is seen on the dropdown, when on android.

Note: No such thing on Desktop and iOS.

Is it a UI bug or something wrong at my end?

[image]

[image]

```js
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
  version: '1.0.0',
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  body: [{
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Route Name",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "spacing": "Large"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      id: "routeId",
      "spacing": "small",
      "choices": routedDd,
      "placeholder": "Select an option",
      "value": "Select an option"
    }
  ],
  actions: [{
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "ABC",
      "id": "adaptivecard",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "task/fetch"
        },
        "taskModule": "adaptivecard",
        "tenantId": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Next",
      "id": "adaptivecard",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "task/fetch"
        },
        "taskModule": "adaptivecard"
      }
    },
  ]
});

return {
  task: {
    type: 'continue',
    value: {
      card: card,
      heigth: 50,
      width: 400,
      title: 'Add Task'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, could you please share your adaptive card json, so that we can test it from our end.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT, I have added the adaptive card json. Let me know any further information required.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, I'm unable to repro the issue, could you please confirm every one in your organization facing this issue or the issue is facing for single user.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, could you please let us know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, could you please let us know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Hey @Jagadeesh-MSFT, will test again from my side and keep you posted.